# Sorting Japanese strings in iroha order

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting

When sorting a list of Japanese strings rendered in either *hiragana* or *katakana*, one convention is to sort them in *[gojūon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goj%C5%ABon)* order. This is the convention imposed by `AlphabeticSort`, as shown by the snippet `AlphabeticSort[RandomSample[Alphabet[Language -> "Hiragana"]], Language -> "Hiragana"]` (and similarly for `Language -> "Katakana"`).

Is it possible to modify `AlphabeticSort` so that strings are sorted in *[iroha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha)* order instead? Alternatively, what else can be used so that one can sort strings in *iroha* order?

Answer (score 5):

To sort words lexicographically according to some alphabet, one can use `SortBy` where the key used for a given word is a list of the ranks of its letters in the given alphabet.  `Lookup` deals with unknown letters; I've supplied the default argument `0` which means unknown letters are before everything else in the alphabet.  I also `PadRight` to a given length because Mathematica sorts `{5}` before `{1, 2, 3}`.

```
ClearAll[SortByAlphabet];
SortByAlphabet[words : {___String}, alphabet : {___String}] :=
  With[{
    letterranks = Association[Table[alphabet[[i]] -> i,
                                    {i, Length[alphabet]}]],
    length = Max[StringLength /@ words]},
   SortBy[words, 
    PadRight[
      Lookup[letterranks, Characters[ToLowerCase[#]], 0], 
      length] &]];
```

then use for instance as

```
SortByAlphabet[{"hello", "world", "this", "code", "is",
  "in", "mathematica", "or", "perhaps", "i", "should",
  "call", "that", "the", "wolfram", "language"}, 
  Join[CharacterRange["n", "z"], CharacterRange["a", "m"]]]
```

Result:

```
{"or", "perhaps", "should", "that", "the", "this",
"world", "wolfram", "code", "call", "hello", "i",
"in", "is", "language", "mathematica"}
```